# How to customize placeholder data from input type="date"

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

At the moment I have this input type date and my question is How to change the text in the input, not to set placeholder but to change "mm/dd/yyyy" to "ZZ/LL/AAAA"?

```
    <input matInput placeholder='Birth date' type='date' 
                                       formControlName='birthDate'>
```

Comment: I don't understand - placeholder is what you are trying to change, so what do you mean by changing placeholder without changing placeholder?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+material+datepicker+language+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: by default for input type="date" placeholder is set like "mm/dd/yyyy" and i can't change it 
I need to be like "ZZ/LL/AAAA"

Answer (score 0):

To change the format you need to use some css and js

Look at this example and use it for your needs.

```js
$("input").on("change", function() {
this.setAttribute(
"data-date",
moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
.format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
)
}).trigger("change")
```

```css
input {
position: relative;
width: 150px; height: 20px;
color: white;
}
input:before {
position: absolute;
top: 3px; left: 3px;
content: attr(data-date);
display: inline-block;
color: black;
}
input::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input::-webkit-clear-button {
display: none;
}
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
right: 0;
color: black;
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" value="2015-08-09">
<br>
<input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY" value="2015-08-09">
```

Comment: I need not to change format but to change the text of input 
Now is "mm/dd/yyyy" but i need to be "mm/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom date format as advised by Angular [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

This is how I did it:

In the .TS file

```
import * as _moment from 'moment'

import {defaultFormat as _rollupMoment} from 'moment'
const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD MMM YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'component.html',
  styleUrls: ['component.css'],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ]
})
```

Be sure to look for your custom format on the official [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) website.

You can change the `dateInput` to any format as advised by [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change date locale by using Date adapter. E.g. set this in your ngOnInit for Swedish date format.

```
this.dateAdapter.setLocale('sv-SE');
```